# JQuery ajax call gets 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I am using the following JS code to send an ajax request:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
            'user_id': '<?=$user->id?>',
            'package_id': '<?=$bundle->package_id?>',
            'YII_CSRF_TOKEN': '<?=Yii::app()->request->csrfToken?>'
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/bundle/ajaxRemove",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                alert("Failed to process user correctly, please try again");
                console.log('xhRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(xhRequest) + "\n");
                console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
            }

        }).done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

The problem is, whenever I submit this code, the server keeps returning a 400 Bad Request Error message.

I've tried submitting as post data instead of json data, and still keep getting the same error.  Tearing my hair out here!

Any idea what I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: So where is your server side code? What debugging have you done on server side to understand why 400 is being returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    data: {
                        user_id: '<?=$user->id?>',
                        package_id: '<?=$bundle->package_id?>',
                        YII_CSRF_TOKEN:'<?=Yii::app()->request->csrfToken?>'},
                    url: '<?php echo Url::to(["/bundle/ajaxRemove"]); ?>',

                    success: function(data) {


                    },
                    error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                    alert("Failed to process user correctly, please try again");
                    console.log('xhRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(xhRequest) + "\n");
                    console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                    console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
                    }
                });
```

Try this one.

Answer (score -1):

Per definition JSON data have to be in double quotes, not single quotes.

If you are sending data by using ajax, it is much easier to give ajax JSON data, then converting it by yourself.

The next point is: Are you trying to use PHP in your JS or do you want to send e.g.:

```
"<?=$user->id?>"
```

Comment: The JSON produced by JSON.stringify will have double quotes. What is happening there is he is passing a js object literal for serialization. No problem there.